# How to avoid empty RSS Feed tags with javascript?

Tags: javascript, feed, rss

I've got my RSS feed in xml file which I can not edit. The problem is that some of the tags inside are empty or they contain other html tags such as <b></b>.
I built my own JavaScript rss feed reader but it's not working unless I will get rid of all empty tags and all html tags. Any ideas?

Example 1 - which doesn't work:

```
/* ... */
<item>
<pubDate>04 Feb</pubDate>
<closeDate>11 Feb</closeDate>
<snappytitle></snappytitle>
<title><b>Web Developer</b></title>
<grade>4</grade>
</item>
/* ... */
```

Example 2 - which does work:

```
/* ... */
<item>
<pubDate>04 Feb</pubDate>
<closeDate>11 Feb</closeDate>

<title>Web Developer</title>
<grade>4</grade>
</item>
/* ... */
```

Comment: "Any ideas" for what? You need an XML sanitizer?

Comment: you're approaching this from the wrong angle.  You're asking "How can I fix this correct XML so I can read it in my broken XML reader?" when you should be asking "How can I fix my broken XML reader since it doesn't read this valid XML?"  This better question also requires you to post your XML reading code.

Comment: Well.. the thing is that I can not edit xml file as it's provided by the third party. To read this xml I am using modify version of the simple javaScript Ajax Feed reader which I found here

I am note sure how to modify this script to still work even if some tags inside of the xml file are empty.. as per example I have before.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. the thing is that I can not edit xml file as it's provided by the third party.
To read this xml I am using modify version of the simple javaScript Ajax Feed reader which I found [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/09/13/rss-and-ajax-a-simple-news-reader.html)

I am note sure how to modify this script to still work even if some tags inside of the xml file are empty.. as per example I have before.

Comment: Comments should be placed in comments, click "add comment".  Answers are meant for answers to the question.